# Express.js post request gives undefined

Tags: node.js, express, rest-client

I used to parse post request body with express.js, but now it started to give undefined when i try to log `req.body.gsm`. `{"gsm":"10"}` this is my post data, and I make the request with a rest client.

```
   app.configure(function(){
      app.use(express.bodyParser());
      app.use(app.router);
      app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
    });

  app.post('/gsm', function (req, res) {

  var gsm = req.body.gsm; //gsm is undefined when i log

  var body = req.body;  //this is the log of body { '{\n"gsm":"10"\n}': '' }

  });
```

Comment: It looks like the problem is not in the nodejs part, but in the client-side code. I.e. the place where you submit the data. Can you please post that script.

Comment: i am using cocoaRestClient and this is the data i post: {"gsm":"10"}

Comment: I wanted to see the actual code which sends the data. Probably you send the data as a string. So, if you use JSON.stringify before to pass the data to the cocoaRestClient, remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're receiving the body as a string, not a JSON object. Express will parse the body into a full JSON object only if the `Content-type: application/json` header is set, see the source code of [*connect*'s `json` middleware](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/json.html).

Just send the same request with the `Content-type: application/json` header.

Sample curl script to test this:

```
$ curl -XPOST -H "Content-type: application/json" -d '{"gsm":"10"}' "http://localhost/gsm"
```